# Spelling difference between passport and visa

Tags: visas, usa, passports

My son is 10 years old. The first name spelling on the passport and the USA Visa has a difference of 1 letter. Will it be ok to travel?

I have a  Gazette  copy and an affidavit that mentions his  name wth the old and new passport number. Will these documents be ok for US immigration?

Comment: What caused the difference? If it was a mistake by the US consulate, you should ask them directly.

Comment: Also: is the spelling consistent in the Machine Readable Zone of all documents?

Comment: Did you replace the passport and change the name in the passport?

Comment: The name change is done in the new passport.it was not by mistake. But the Visa in in the old passport wth the old name..Is tht ok??can the child travel??

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Gazette copy and an affidavit that mentions his name with the old and new passport number. Will these documents be ok for US immigration?

They should be but it is better to contact the consulate for a name change since you've changed your passport name (especially if this is the consulate's mistake).